# Using a C# windows form variable in a asmx web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a windows form project in C# which contains a Form having different controls. I want to separate the variable named 'value' from my code which comes under a click event of a button. Below is the screenshot for the same:

[image: click event of button containing 'value' variable]

Now, i want to use the current value of this variable in a asmx web service. Is this even possible? If yes, how?

Comment: kindly please post the code instead of image.

Comment: Code is little long, kindly click on the image to get a clear view.

Comment: Did you code the webservice? It accepts 'value' as an input, but without actually seeing the code for the service we cannot make any assumptions regarding what the webservice does with the input.

Comment: I have yet to write the code for web service, as of now i want to understand how i can use the data inside 'value' variable in a web service method.

Comment: PokeValue, PokeValue2, PokeValue3 are TextBox?

Comment: yes, these all are textboxes and for now we are only considering the 'PokeValue' textbox whose value is being stroed in 'value' variable.

Comment: The logical thing to do would be to send the value to the asmx. But since you don't really explain the situation or provide any code that really relates to the issue (and the code isn't long. Don't post it as a picture) it's hard to say what you're even trying to do.

Comment: Sami, I just want to use the data inside 'value' variable in my web service anyhow. My problem is how can i get the windows form project and my web service linked or how can i use this 'value' variable in web service.

Comment: Here is the code      if (!bOnAdvise) { Advise_Click(Advise, new System.EventArgs());}
try{if (bOnAdvise)
 {timestamp = PokeTimestamp.Text;
if (PokeValue2.Text.Length == 0) {
value = PokeValue.Text;
 if (timestamp.Length > 0){ LMX_Server.Write2(hLMX, hItem, value, timestamp, uindex1); }                      else
 {LMX_Server.Write(hLMX, hItem, value, uindex1); } } else
{if (timestamp.Length > 0)
{LMX_Server.Write2(hLMX, hItem, intarray, timestamp, uindex1);
}  else
 {LMX_Server.Write(hLMX, hItem, intarray, uindex1);
                        }

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use Properties to publish this values instead of assigning it to a local variables.

```
public string PokeValueText
{
    get {return PokeValue.Text;}
}
```

You can use it in your form or externally.

```
LMXServer.Write(hLMX, hItem, PokeValueText, uindex1);

YourForm.PokeValueText;
```

Comment: yes, that's okay i can do that but the real problem is will i be able to use this 'PokeValueText' value in a asmx web service?

Comment: why not? asmx web service is running?  have you got/built the wrapper class for this web service?

Comment: i have created many asmx web services, so i have an idea about it. And, no the web service is not running yet because i don't know what should i write to use the variable from my windows application. The real question is how will i get the windows form and web services linked? Do i need to create the dll of windows project and use it in web service or something else of that sort?

Comment: If I have understood correctly: you should publish your web service, then, add a web service reference to your winform app. That will generate a wrapper class with the published methods: something like `ws.YourMethod(string param1, string param2, string param2), and then simply call this method within your winform app.

Comment: okay, thank you! But can't we do it the other way around ..using windows application in web service?

Comment: a web service is a windows application, if you mean a winform: no, it's not possible in a client-server environment to use a winforms app from a web service. the service is executing in server side, the consumer call the service in the client side. I'm sorry but I don't understand what are you trying to do.